# Drop files into dockbar application

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard

I would like to just drag a file over my application in the dockbar and use it in my application, preferably with some event like file_got_dropped or something in that way

Answer (score 0):

Just override the method `- (void)application:(NSApplication *)theApplication openFiles:(NSArray *)filenames` inside your application's delegate class.